# how to round a number to 2 decimal place? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rounding

Im trying to round a number to 2 decimal place. I have tried the following but not having any luck? Can somebody please help me and tell me where im going wrong??

```
var winPercentage = totalWins/(totalWins+totalLost)*100;
winPercentage.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('win-percentage').innerHTML = winPercentage + " %";
```

i search and tried this but to be honest i have no idea what it is?

```
var winPercentage = totalWins/(totalWins+totalLost)*100;
expr {double(round(100*winPercentage))/100}
document.getElementById('win-percentage').innerHTML = winPercentage + " %";
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input and and expected output because your code is correct for what you have asked.

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work? its displaying numbers like 48.38709677419355 %    When i would like 48.38

Comment: and when its 40.5 i want it round to 40.50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following syntax instead and alter it to your needs

```
var num = 5.1;

num.toFixed(2); //will become 5.10
```

Comment: var winPercentage = totalWins/(totalWins+totalLost)*100;winPercentage.toFixed(2);
                    document.getElementById('win-percentage').innerHTML = winPercentage + " %";

Comment: var winPercentage = totalWins/(totalWins+totalLost)*100;winPercentage.toFixed(2);
                    document.getElementById('win-percentage').innerHTML = winPercentage + " %";

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea with `toFixed(2)`. The problem is that it **returns the formatted number**, it does not alter the variable it was called on. In other words, you just need to assign it back the the variable you were using:

```
winPercentage = winPercentage.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been bugging me for a while : ) thanks